# skimage transform.resize negative impact on RAM

Tags: python, image-processing, optimization, scikit-image

I noticed recently that using [transform.resize](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) fills my RAM (like a lot: 23Go). Here is my function

```
def resizePics(i):
    target_size = 500
    h, w = i.shape[0], i.shape[1]

    if h > w:      # crop to get a squared pic
        crop_size = round((h - w)/2)
        i = i[crop_size: h -crop_size, 0:w]
    elif h < w:
        crop_size = round((w - h)/2)
        i = i[0:h, crop_size:w-crop_size]

    i = transform.resize(i, (target_size,target_size), mode="constant", preserve_range=True) ##! HERE !##

    return(i)
```

And where I invoke it (data is a pandas dataframe)

```
pool = ThreadPool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())

data["img"] = pool.map(resizePics, data["img"])

pool.close() 
pool.close()
```

[**Main Hypotheses**]

I noticed that the kind of values for my matrices change a lot after using this function (even if I use preserve_range=True). This is before transform.resize:

```
data.head(5)
0   chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person64_bacteria_3...   pneumonia   [[98, 100, 103, 104, 105, 107, 111, 114, 113, ...   504     144.0
1   chest_xray/train/NORMAL/NORMAL2-IM-1342-0001.jpeg   normal  [[0, 173, 163, 154, 144, 140, 132, 131, 129, 1...   1078    138.0
2   chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person1441_bacteria...   pneumonia   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...   1144    155.0
3   chest_xray/train/NORMAL/NORMAL2-IM-0576-0001.jpeg   normal  [[30, 31, 31, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 29, 27, 28, ...   1422    135.0
4   chest_xray/train/NORMAL/NORMAL2-IM-0660-0001.jpeg   normal  [[0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1,...   950     133.0
```

This is after:

```
data.head(5)
0   chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person64_bacteria_3...   pneumonia   [[196.00400000000008, 197.000096, 197.02799999...   504     144.0
1   chest_xray/train/NORMAL/NORMAL2-IM-1342-0001.jpeg   normal  [[38.89042000000035, 38.15600000000006, 36.734...   1078    138.0
2   chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person1441_bacteria...   pneumonia   [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...   1144    155.0
3   chest_xray/train/NORMAL/NORMAL2-IM-0576-0001.jpeg   normal  [[15.940252000000065, 17.550252000001198, 15.6...   1422    135.0
4   chest_xray/train/NORMAL/NORMAL2-IM-0660-0001.jpeg   normal  [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...   950     133.0
```

It seems to me that the impact on the RAM has something to do with pixels being encoded from int -> floats.

[**Question**]: is there a way to tweek transform.resize in order to

- stick to ints
- constraint the range of number after the , (say, 3 decimals)

Answer (score 0):

For the vast majority of the `scikit-image` functions the internal representation is `float`. Especially, where some kind of smoothing/anti-alisaing/etc is required. Only this way we can guarantee that the output is as precise and informative as possible. To answer your questions:

> [Question]: is there a way to tweek transform.resize in order to
>
> - stick to ints
> - constraint the range of number after the , (say, 3 decimals)

"negative" to both bullet points :). You should manually cast the output to whatever dtype you want by using, e.g., `{resize_output}.astype(np.uint8, casting='unsafe')` or `numpy.around({resize_output}, decimals=3)`.

I'm curious to know, however, the details of your benchmark. 23GB is a lot. If you could prepare a minimal example of your code that shows the high memory usage, please, post it on our GitHub bugtracker (https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues).

Comment: I just tried to round and change type of the matrices in the end of my function but it didn't change a lot of thing. It might be a problem related to the way pandas serialize or de-serialize (or whatever it does) because my original data is only made of 1.2Go of images and it becomes 4Go as soon as I import these in a dataframe

Comment: a minimal example of my code would involve to have the dataset, also but I can post something on Git

Comment: That's a typical behavior, I must say. See this article by one of the Pandas creators - http://wesmckinney.com/blog/apache-arrow-pandas-internals/ .